# Two select count queries and then calculate percentage

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'd like to combine two queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM abc;
SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM ABC WHERE Status='Active';
```

And then calculate the percentage (by taking the 2nd query divided by first query). I'd like to achieve this in one single query. What i've attempted so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS A FROM abc
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Status) AS B FROM ABC WHERE Status='Active';
UNION 
SELECT(COUNT(Status)*100/SELECT COUNT(*) FROM abc)) AS %ofAB FROM abc WHERE Status='Active'
```

What I get:

```
A
--
31
36
86,11111111
```

What I want:

```
A  | B  | %ofAB
---------------------
36 | 31 | 86,1111111%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
    SUM(IIF(Status = 'Active', 1, 0)) AS ActiveCount,
    ROUND((SUM(IIF(Status = 'Active', 1, 0)) * 100/ COUNT(*)),2) AS PctActive
FROM
    Abc
```

EDIT: Didn't notice that this was for Access. I don't know if `CAST` is available in Access, so you may need to use an equivalent function to make sure that the integers don't simply yield 1 or 0. It's possible that Access will convert a division into a decimal automatically, but in SQL Server it does not.