# Filtering Data from a Query with SQL

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I'm really running into issues with this SQL code I'm using. I've been posying about this, but not really getting answers. I tried to adapt [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441779/two-select-count-queries-and-then-calculate-percentage) to what I am trying to do, but I keep getting the screen shot of the error message screen grabbed below.

```
SELECT LoginID, ShiftNumber, PalletQTY, Group, ShiftDate
FROM Database
COUNT(PalletQTY) AS TotalCount
SUM(IF(Group='PUT',1,0)) AS ActiveCount,
ROUND((SUM(IF(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD='PUT',1,0))*100/COUNT(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY)),2) AS PctActive
FROM WBR_RW.TALLY_TRAN_MSTR TALLY_TRAN_MSTR
```

[image]

Now, there are many dates and many names with each date, so I want the code recognize that. I'm not sure if the code I'm trying to adapt is able to do that.

I'm really struggling at this point for how to make this code work, or find code that may work. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if additional information is needed.

**EDIT**
[image]

I am trying view data of a person who is spent more than 75% of his time doing "PUT" for a specific date.

An example of what I'm trying to do is (Calculated manually)

McMillan has 3 items associated with his name 6/15/2017. 1 of those is "PUT". The total of the "PUT" items for that date for him are 132. The sum of everything associated with his name for that date is 167. 132/167 = 0.79. 0.79>0.75 so I want his data to show in my query results.
Malone has 4 items associated with his name on 6/15/2017. 1 of those is "PUT". The "PUT" summed is 4. The sum of all 4 items is 36. 4/36=0.11 0.11 < 0.75, so I want to get rid of that data.

Comment: The Oracle database produces Oracle errors.  I added the appropriate tag.

Comment: It would help if you showed your table structure, sample data and the expected results for that data - all as formatted text, not just as vague-ish description. You're including `PalletQTY` in the select list and group-by, but also an aggregate of that, which doesn't really make sense. And it ins't obvious if `Group` and `PRI_GRP_CD` are the same column really; same with `PalletQTY` and `FULL_PLLT_QTY` maybe.

Comment: That is not formatted text. Please see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support `if()`.  Use proper Oracle syntax.  I think the query should look more like this:

```
SELECT LoginID, ShiftNumber, PalletQTY, "Group", ShiftDate,
       COUNT(PalletQTY) AS TotalCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN "Group" = 'PUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActiveCount,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD = 'PUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100 / 
             COUNT(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY), 2) AS PctActive
FROM WBR_RW.TALLY_TRAN_MSTR TALLY_TRAN_MSTR
GROUP BY LoginID, ShiftNumber, PalletQTY, "Group", ShiftDate;
```

Comment: I just tried that, and I got the error message, verbatim "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @Lampoa - that's because of missing commas between column expressions, after `ShiftDate` and `TotalCount` - which were missing in your original too. (Not sure that the `from database` was doing there...). Try the edited code.

Comment: @AlexPoole Hey, thanks! it worked, but it just doesn't do what I want it to do... talking to other people on here, it seems like what I'm looking for is pretty simple to do, I just have virtually no experience with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the basic syntax issues Gordon pointed out, you seem to be confusing the `count()` and `sum()` aggregate functions. You can do both, but from your description you're interest in the total quantity of pallets, not the number of entries for the group type.

You seem to want something more like this, Using dummy data based on your original description:

```
-- CTE for dummy data
with tally_tran_mstr (loginid, shiftdate, shiftnumber, pri_grp_cd, palletqty) as 
(
  select 'Steve', date '2017-06-15', 1, 'PUT', 40 from dual
  union all select 'Steve', date '2017-06-15', 1, 'PUT', 80 from dual
  union all select 'Steve', date '2017-06-15', 1, 'PUT', 45 from dual
  union all select 'Steve', date '2017-06-15', 1, '???', 7 from dual
  union all select 'Steve', date '2017-06-15', 1, '???', 5 from dual
  union all select 'Steve', date '2017-06-15', 1, '???', 3 from dual
  union all select 'Steve', date '2017-06-15', 1, '???', 1 from dual
)
-- end of CTE for dummy data
select loginid, shiftnumber, shiftdate,
  count(*) as totalcount,
  count(case when pri_grp_cd = 'PUT' then 1 end) as activecount,
  round(100 * count(case when pri_grp_cd = 'PUT' then 1 end) / count(*), 2)
    as pctactivecount,
  sum(palletqty) as totalqty,
  sum(case when pri_grp_cd = 'PUT' then palletqty else 0 end) as activeqty,
  round(100 * sum(case when pri_grp_cd = 'PUT' then palletqty else 0 end) /
    sum(palletqty), 2) as pctactiveqty
from tally_tran_mstr
group by loginid, shiftnumber, shiftdate;

LOGIN SHIFTNUMBER SHIFTDATE  TOTALCOUNT ACTIVECOUNT PCTACTIVECOUNT   TOTALQTY  ACTIVEQTY PCTACTIVEQTY
----- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ------------
Steve           1 2017-06-15          7           3          42.86        181        165        91.16
```

I've taken `palletqty` and `group` out of the select-list because if they are in there they have to be included in the group-by clause, which won't do the counting and summing at the right level.

That should give you one row of output for each person on each day/shift they have records for.

If you want to exclude the results rows where the percentage doesn't meet some threshold then you can add a `having` clause:

```
...
group by loginid, shiftnumber, shiftdate
having sum(case when pri_grp_cd = 'PUT' then palletqty else 0 end) /
  sum(palletqty) > 0.8;
```

You may prefer to avoid repeating some of the terms; you can move the count/sum/group into a subquery (inline view), and then filter that with a `where` clause instead of a `having` clause:

```
select loginid, shiftnumber, shiftdate, totalcount, activecount,
  round(100 * activecount / totalcount, 2) as pctactivecount,
  totalqty, activeqty, round(100 * activeqty / totalqty, 2) as pctactiveqty
from (
  select loginid, shiftnumber, shiftdate,
    count(*) as totalcount,
    count(case when pri_grp_cd = 'PUT' then 1 end) as activecount,
    sum(palletqty) as totalqty,
    sum(case when pri_grp_cd = 'PUT' then palletqty else 0 end) as activeqty
  from tally_tran_mstr
  group by loginid, shiftnumber, shiftdate
)
where activeqty / totalqty > 0.8;
```